# What is the time complexity of the whole algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, modulo

I am new to asymptotic notation and here is the algorithm. What is the worst case tight bond for time complexity and why?

```
F(A,B) {  //A and B are positive
  while A>0 
    print(A mod B)
    A=A div B
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity of this:

```
F(A,B) {  //A and B are positive
  while A>0 
    A=A/B
}
```

is equal to the number of times the loop will execute, let's call that `l` and is equal to how many times B has to divide A to make "A > 0" false.

From this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320420/time-complexity-of-a-modulo-operation), we know that:

> Algorithm D in 4.3.1 of Knuth's book "The Art of Computer Programming" (Volume 2) performs any long division in O(m) steps, where `m` is the number of digits of A, so we have an upper bound.

Thus the Time Complexity is: *O(l * m)*

Now this:

```
print(A mod B)
```

assuming that IO is constant (that's something of course that's not correct in real-wolrd), you need the complexity of the modulo itself, which from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132487/what-is-the-runtime-of-a-modulus-operation), we know it's:

> O(log A log B)

and will run `l` times.

As a result, we have:

**O(l * (m + log A log B))**

Comment: how about we now consider the whole algorithm? whats the time complexity? Thx a lot

Comment: `O(l * (m + log A log B))` @WILLIAM, it's the final sentence. BTW, don't forget to *accept* one of the answers you got! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very good question. First if B is unity, the algorithm will never complete. Presumably B must be 2 or greater. So we have O(log A) steps. But the question now is whether the division is itself an "operation" or not. If A and B are unbounded, then inherently it must also be logarithmic. But normally the code will be running on a processor that implements all divisions in 32 or 64 bits, and it can't divide an number out of range. So generally we say that divisions are "operations".

If we say division is logarithimic and B is small then we're O(log A)^2.